# How can a team share private video screen captures?

Tags: video, collaboration

Part of our QA process is capturing UI bugs on video and embedding these videos in bug reports. Is there a service out there that lets a group share videos in a centralized location (not individual accounts) and privately (not accessible to the public). A private YouTube channel where contributers can upload videos would be exactly what we need - but, alas, no such thing from Google.

Comment: Doesn't your bug reporting tool allow you to attach files to issues?

Comment: Yea, but it's not meant for lots of heavy files. Mainly for screenshots and log files. If we use it as a video sharing solution I'm afraid it would really strain the system (Redmine).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) (DB) setup proposal :

- each member of the QA team has its
  own DB
- create a DB account
  "QA-team" linked with your
  centralized location (eg, a server of
  your company)
- create a shared
  folder involving all QA members +
  server DB account
- place screencasts in the shared folder and include a link to the internal server file
  when writing a bug report

Bonus: have a look at [User guide to dropbox shared folder](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16310/user-guide-to-dropbox-shared-folders/) if you're interesting to make a RSS feed of the shared folder changes, or tweet each changes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the perfect solution. It's called [Bloomfire](http://www.bloomfire.com/). They have a video capture service that works straight out of the browser, no installation necessary. And then videos are added to an internal knowledge-base type system where team members can view and comment on the videos. I find this to be a fantastic solution for QA video captures of UI bugs, especially for web UI (since capturing works straight out of the browser).

Very slick UI, too. I use the free edition and it's enough. They also have an iPhone app, so I can see video bug reports instantly as they are created. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

You can [upload videos to Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1047043) & share them privately among a group. Google Docs has a YouTube-like video player.